# wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. Unsupported value type (object)

Tags: wordpress, object, prepared-statement

I an recieving this notice in my error log since switching to wpdb->prepare, I am using SimpleXML to bring in data then input into a table

```
[code]
    $dataset = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
        foreach($dataset->item as $list) {
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`id`,`number`,`string`) VALUES (%d,%d,%s) ", $list->id, $list->number, $list->string ) ) ;
        }
    }
[/code]
```

THe insert is working, but each time throuws the OBJECT warning.  Can I not use the $list object even though I am using its value as $list->xxx

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem as you have and found out that accessing an element from the XML source still remains as a SimpleXMLElement object and you have to convert it in the right type
In the case of a string, you have to use the __toString() function from SimpleXMLElement Class

Exemple :

```
    <?php

    $datas = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_content('my_xml_sheet_path'));
    foreach($datas->event as $event):
        var_dump($event->title);echo '<br/>';
        var_dump($event->title->__toString()); echo '<br/><br/>';
        exit();
    endforeach;

    ?>
```

Returns :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4755 (1) { [0]=> string(13) "Event 1 Title" }
string(13) "Event 1 Title"

object(SimpleXMLElement)#4755 (1) { [0]=> string(13) "Event 2 Title" }
string(13) "Event 2 Title"

object(SimpleXMLElement)#4755 (1) { [0]=> string(13) "Event 3 Title" }
string(13) "Event 3 Title"
```

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it solved my problem

I hope this will help !

#### Update 5/5/2018

- Just stumbled upon this response, which gave me what I needed, but needed PHP 5.3 update.
- At the time of this writing `__toString()` is deprecated, data type casting `(string)` now works... like a boss, ie

---

```
<?php

    $datas = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_content('my_xml_sheet_path'));
    foreach($datas->event as $event):
        var_dump($event->title);
        echo '<br/>';
        $eventTitle = (string)$event->title;
        var_dump($eventTitle); 
        echo '<br/><br/>';
        exit();
    endforeach;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a var dump of list, empty items returned an object :

object(SimpleXMLElement)#1776 (0)

I believe this is throwing the error as expected while using an object.

Comment: So even checking the values returned from $list->xx all are still considered objects.  I think there is an issue I am not understanding with this